# How can we get List<String> from System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, t4

I am using T4 Template to generate c# class. I need to generate shadow class from another class, Class1.

In Class1, I have `TypeAttribute` which can tell what is the type of Property in Class1.

By using reflection I am getting the Type specified in the `TypeAttribute`.

I am not getting any standard way to get the Type for the Generics in unmangled format.

I need `List<String>` from System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].

I am using T4Toolbox for T4Template.

Is T4Toolbox is providing any such feature to deal with generics while generating c# code?

Thank you.

Comment: That is already a `List<string>`, you merely see the name that the CLR uses.

Comment: @HansPassant He's trying to convert a `Type` object into the string representation needed to replicate it in a `.cs` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I threw together when I was playing around with T4 templates recently.

```
static class Exts
{
    public static string ToCSharpString(this Type type, StringBuilder sb = null)
    {
        sb = sb ?? new StringBuilder();

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            sb.Append(type.Name.Split('`')[0]);
            sb.Append('<');
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var tp in type.GenericTypeArguments)
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(", ");
                }

                sb.Append(tp.ToCSharpString());
            }
            sb.Append('>');
        }
        else if (type.IsArray)
        {
            sb.Append(type.GetElementType().ToCSharpString());
            sb.Append("[]");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(type.Name);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

There's probably more special cases but it covers generics and arrays.

```
var list = typeof(List<string>).ToCSharpString();
// List<String>

var dict = typeof(Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>).ToCSharpString();
// Dictionary<Int32, HashSet<String>>

var array = typeof(Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>[]).ToCSharpString();
// Dictionary<Int32, HashSet<String>>[]
```